# Objeto complejo en MongoDB y creación del CRUD con Express y Nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Actualmente tengo una base de datos con el siguiente `Schema`:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var img_Schema = new Schema({
    id_student: {type:String, require:true},
    name: {type:String, require:true},
    lastname: {type:String, require:true},
    year_tag: [ {
        year: String,
        course: String,
        area_tag: [ {
            area: String,
            subject_tag: [ {
                subject: String,
                qualification: String
            } ]
        } ],
    } ],
    creator:{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
});
var Imagen = mongoose.model("Imagen",img_Schema);
module.exports = Imagen;
```

Estoy realizando el `Get` y el `Post` del objeto padre de la siguiente forma:

```
var express = require("express");
var Imagen = require("./models/imagenes");
var router = express.Router();
var fs = require("fs");
var redis = require("redis");

var client = redis.createClient()

var image_finder_middleware = require("./middlewares/find_image");

router.get("/",function(req,res){
Imagen.find({})
     .populate("creator")
     .exec(function(err,imagenes){
        if(err) console.log(err);
           res.render("app/home",{imagenes: imagenes});
        })

  });

//Student
router.route("/imagenes")
.get(function(req,res){
  Imagen.find({creator: res.locals.user._id},function(err,imagenes){
     if(err){ res.redirect("/app");return;}
     res.render("app/imagenes/index",{imagenes: imagenes});
  });
})
.post(function(req,res){
  var data = {
     id_student: req.body.id_student,
     name: req.body.name,
     lastname: req.body.lastname,
     year_tag: [],
     creator: res.locals.user._id
  }
  console.log(data);

  var imagen = new Imagen(data);
  imagen.save(function(err){
     if(!err){

        res.redirect("/app/imagenes/"+imagen._id)
        console.log(imagen)
     }
     else{
        console.log(imagen);
        res.render(err);
     }
  });
});
```

Y de la siguiente forma hago el `Delete` del elemento padre, el `Post` para un elemento hijo y el `Get` para el elemento padre completo:

```
//Crud Student and Post Year_tag
router.route("/imagenes/:id")
.get(function(req,res){
  res.render("app/imagenes/show");
})
//create a object in year_tag
.post(function(req,res){
  Imagen.findById(req.params.id, function(err,imagen){
     res.locals.imagen.year_tag.push({
        year: req.body.year,
        course: req.body.course,
        area_tag: []
     });
     res.locals.imagen.save(function(err){
        if(!err){
           res.render("app/imagenes/show",{imagen:imagen});
           console.log()
        }else{
           res.render("app/imagenes/"+imagen.id+"/year",{imagen:imagen});
           console.log(err)
        }
     })
  })
})
 //Delete a Student
.delete(function(req,res){
  Imagen.findOneAndRemove({_id: req.params.id},function(err){
     if(!err){
         res.redirect("/app/imagenes");
     }else{
        console.log(err);
        res.redirect("/app/imagenes"+req.params.id);
     }
  });
})
```

Finalmente estoy necesitando hacer el `CRUD` de los demás elementos Hijos que en el `Schema` de la base de datos aparecen con los nombres de `area_tag` y `subject_tag`.

Agradecería mucho cualquier ayuda o consejo que puedan brindarme en este tema.